# How to access internal valid IP through internet?

Tags: networking, router, ip

Suppose I have a router with this valid IP address (it's not real): 9.9.9.9

So this router is identified by this ID. The internet is available through this router.

Another computer wants to access 9.9.9.9 over internet, But because 9.9.9.9 is set in router, it never sends the request over internet and Immediately shows 192.168.0.5

[image]

I want to see 9.9.9.9 via internet, But because router is intelligent(!) it doesn't send client's request to ISP.

I know that ISP only identifies a valid IP address, But router doesn't reply to the request through the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some kind of port forwarding. In your router you must forward every port you need to access from internet, for example, if you want to serve web content from your internal network, to the internet, you must forward port number 80, or if you want to access through the internet, your internal system using remote desktop (RDP) you must forward port number 3389.

I managed some of this before but I don't remember exactly what was it's sheet name, it's port forwarding that ask you external port, internal IP and internal port and every request to your valid IP through Internet will be forwarded to internal IP over port you defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

192.168.0.0 through 192.168.255.255 are a IANA-recognized private addressing range.  They are set aside for internal use only, and no ISP will route to them publicly.

If someone tries to send traffic to 192.168.0.1 for example, out of their ISP's equipment through the Internet, their ISP will instantly drop it.

You need to use NAT, or tunnel using a VPN such as OpenVPN.

Comment: May I could not explain My question, my `router` ignores sending client request to internet. I guess there is some router configurations I've missed.

Comment: If you're trying to access your external IP from a computer within your LAN behind the router, expecting it to NAT back into your network, it might not work unless your router supports hairpinning the connections back into the NAT.  This explains a bit more: http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Hairpin_NAT - Please also note that if this is your situation, your hairpinned traffic is not actually traversing the Internet, just being thrown back into your network.

Comment: Thanks Hair-pinning is exactly what I want, 1- How can I find out if My router has Hair-pinning or not. For sure my device has a specification sheet, but what is this capability name in specification Sheet? 2- please update your answer, I guess your comment is true answer.